# Do sharks attack you if you're using a water vehicle?

Tags: far-cry-3

I have a real-life phobia that, unfortunately, carries over to video games when I play them. I don't like swimming and not being able to see below me. So when I swim, I'm unable to see sharks and jelly fish and whatever else is in the water.

Luckily for me, there are plenty of water vehicles in the game. Will I get attacked if I'm using one of these? Is there a better way to get around the islands than using these vehicles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Far Cry Wiki article on sharks](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Bull_Shark):

> Bull Sharks are animals found in oceans of Far Cry 3. They attack when the player is submerged or in the water, but will not attack players mounted on jet skis. When in a certain radius from a shark, and in the water, they become noticeably agitated and make a beeline for their prey.

You can kill sharks by running them over with a boat or jetski or by shooting them from a boat or from land.

---

Note that a lot of the artifacts in the game are in shark waters, and I think there's also a storyline mission which requires you to dive in shark water.

Comment: Yes, I think one of them is scripted so you can't avoid encountering the shark. Watch out for the crocodiles in the rivers as well, they made me jump out of my skin!

Comment: Oh man, I am really not going to like that part

Comment: Oh man, crocodiles. I believe there's one mission where there's one in a cave, sort of late in the game (I think), and that one was the first one I encountered. Had been wondering for hours whether or not there were crocs in the game. Needless to say, I wasn't too happy.