# Sharkskins in Far Cry 3

Tags: far-cry-3

I am attempting to find sharks in Far Cry 3, so that I might... ahem, "obtain" shark skins.  The guides I have [seen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173684/do-sharks-attack-you-if-youre-using-a-water-vehicle/173718#173718) list how to kill sharks, but now how to find them.  How do you find sharks to kill in Far Cry 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sharks can be found in most open water areas in Far Cry 3.

Look for the shark symbol on the map, you should see several.
[image: sharks!]

Comment: Mmm, visual aid.

Comment: Thankfully your guns obey the "Saving Private Ryan" type physics, and not real world physics so you can shoot them in the water no matter how deep they are, from the shore. The answer above shows where to find them, use your binoculars and it will highlight them pretty easily too and you can blast away from safety.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the map, you will notice that there are animal symbols drawn on various locations. Simply head over to the location where the shark symbol is drawn and more likely than not an innocent shark is swimming around for you to cull.

Answer (score 1):

Just get in a boat.  Something you can stand in and use a gun.  Not a jetsky.  Get a nice big boat, go out to sea wait for the sharks and shoot
 them.  Watch where there go and dive in, when no other sharks are about.  When I played Far Cry 3 for about the 7th time I decided to do all the hunting before following the story.  I got all the upgrades first, then I took on the story.  It made it much easier for me.  But like I say, 7th play through for me.  It takes me a while to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just look around the island's shore, there are plenty of sharks everywhere.
Ideally, you get yourself a boat, too, for some easy travel.

The animal symbols usually help, but sharks really just appear anywhere in the open sea.